Web3 Python async request for get_all_entries are failing
async_w3 = AsyncWeb3(AsyncWeb3.AsyncHTTPProvider(rpc))

async_contract = async_w3.eth.contract(address=ADDRESS, abi=ENV.TOKEN_ABI)
async_contract.events.Transfer().create_filter(fromBlock=crawl_block-block_gap,toBlock=crawl_block )
total_supply = await async_contract.functions.totalSupply().call()
data__ = await event_filter.get_all_entries()


Errors :
web3\manager.py", line 293, in formatted_response
raise ValueError(error)
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'filter not found'}

I was aspecting a list [] as the result of get_all_entries

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
